# Monaco Editor throws Uncaught ReferenceError: monaco is not defined Error after install through npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, monaco-editor

I am trying to implement a monaco diff editor in my project that compares two json objects. Now I am still quite new to node.js and node modules, so perhaps the answer to this might be easier than I think.

I installed the monaco editor using the npm install command and that worked perfectly fine. The dependencie has been added to my package.json and appears in my node-module folder. However, when I try calling the createDiffEditor function using `const editor = monaco.editor.createDiffEditor(document.getElementById('editor'), editorConfiguration);` the console throws an Uncaught Reference error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: monaco is not defined
    at monacoEditor (diff.js:109:20)
    at convertJson (diff.js:33:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.toggleEditor (diff.js:94:5)
```

This is my code (it's one file but I seperated the functions for better readability):

```
import { getPanes } from "../views/panes.js";

const listenerHide = document.getElementById("hide");
listenerHide.addEventListener("click", toggleEditor);

var editorActive = false;
```

```
// Takes two visualized network graphs and transform them into json format
function convertJson(){
  
  var subPane;
  var refPane;
  var panes = getPanes();

  // get selected pane Ids
  subPane = document.querySelector('#subdiff').value;
  refPane = document.querySelector('#refdiff').value;

  // get entire pane based on Id
  subPane = panes[subPane];
  refPane = panes[refPane];

  // export cy as string
  let subJson = subPane.cy.json(true);
  let refJson = refPane.cy.json(true);

  // turn Json to String testing purposes
  const subString = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + JSON.stringify(subJson, undefined, 2);
  const refString = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + JSON.stringify(refJson, undefined, 2);
  console.log(subJson);
  console.log(refJson);

  monacoEditor(subJson, refJson);

}
```

```
// toggles the Editor in the browser
function toggleEditor(){
  var editorCheck = document.getElementById('hide');
  var editorBox = document.getElementById('editor');

  if(editorCheck.checked){
    editorBox.style.display = "block";
    editorActive = true;
    convertJson();
  }
  else{
    editorBox.style.display = "none";
    editorActive = false;
  }
}
```

```
// Actual Editor creation
function monacoEditor(subJson, refJson){

  var editorConfiguratiion = {
    fontSize: 15
  }

  
    const editor = monaco.editor.createDiffEditor(document.getElementById('editor'), editorConfiguration);
    editor.setModel({
      original: monaco.editor.createModel(refJson, 'json'),
      modified: monaco.editor.createModel(subJson, 'json'),
    });

}
```

I have done some research. Many of those who encountered similar issues solved it by loading the module using require function similar to the [official example](https://codepen.io/akshitsarin/pen/VwexpQL). However, for me this just throws the same error as require isn't integrated anymore by default. So I tried including require and I come across the same error except that the error is thrown at requiere.config as that is apparently a function that is not defined:

```
import { getPanes } from "../views/panes.js";
import * as require from "./require.js";
```

```
function monacoEditor(subJson, refJson){

  require.config({
    paths: { 'vs': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.19.2/min/vs' }
  });


  var editorConfiguratiion = {
    fontSize: 15
  }

  require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], () => {
    const editor = monaco.editor.createDiffEditor(document.getElementById('editor'), editorConfiguration);
    editor.setModel({
      original: monaco.editor.createModel(refJson, 'json'),
      modified: monaco.editor.createModel(subJson, 'json'),
    });
  });
}
```

In one of the StackOverflow posts I came across someone stated that require comes with monaco itself and a seperate import is not needed, but that does not make sense to me. How can it be integrated in the module but it's also necessary to load the module in the first place?

I feel like the issue is that I am not importing/loading the monaco editor properly, but I also can't seem to figure out how to do it properly.

Something I also found irritating is that no script tag showed up in my script.spy file and when I tried to add it manually it threw an `GET "localhost:3000" 404 Error` since the editor.main.js is not in my public folder.

Does anyone know a solution to this?